# npm script protractor command is throwing error

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to run conf.js file using npm script. This conf.js file is created inside JSFilesRepo/config folder after running tsc command because i am using typescript with protractor-jasmine.

When i go to cmd at package.json level and run:

```
protractor JSFilesRepo/config/conf.js
```

it works fine but when i try to run it with npm script (npm run test)from package.json level gives me error

```
"scripts": {   
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/protractor JSFilesRepo/config/conf.js",
  },
```

error:
Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.

I have updated webdriver-manager. I believe it is something to do with path.

Comment: These are both great answers. I think it depends on how you are running Protractor. If you are launching it with "local" or "direct connect", then you need to run the local version of the webdriver-manager. See the "scripts" answer. The files are downloaded locally and your locally installed Protractor understands where the browser binaries are. The second answer about global is important too. If you are using a globally installed Protractor, then hopefully you download your binaries globally (I think that will work too)

Answer (score 2):

`protractor JSFilesRepo/config/conf.js` uses global protractor which you had executed `webdriver-manager update` on it.

But `node_modules/.bin/protractor JSFilesRepo/config/conf.js` uses local protractor (under your project) which you have not execute `webdriver-manager update` for it.

Execute `./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update` from the root project folder.

Comment: but it is not working for this also :  "test": "protractor JSFilesRepo/config/conf.js",

Answer (score 2):

add a script in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {   
    "WDupdate":"node node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/protractor JSFilesRepo/config/conf.js"
 }
```

run `WDupdate` and then followed by your test command

Comment: Also I would like to add that you do not have to write "node node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/bin/webdriver-manager". In scripts, it already understands what webdriver-manager is. So simply add `"wdupdate": "webdriver-manager update"` and it will work. Same thing with `"protractor"` on the next line.

Comment: Have you updated your test script to "test": "protractor JSFilesRepo/config/conf.js" ?